# Using jQuery formBuilder plugin in a React.js app (issue with Sortable)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins, formbuilder

I've been trying to get the jQuery formBuilder plugin to work in a React app. I've also contacted the plugin developer, but since I'm fairly new to React I want ask also here in case I'm missing something obvious.

The plugin is this one: http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/

Steps to reproduce my issue:

1)
Create an empty React app with these (reference: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html):

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app`
```

2)
Install latest versions of jquery, jquery-ui and formBuilder to the React app with:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install jquery-ui --save
npm install formBuilder --save
```

So in package.json these are then added:

```
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"formBuilder": "^2.9.8"
```

3)
In app.js top of file add:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require('jquery-ui');
require('formBuilder');
```

I came to use the above lines after first googling for various issues like "$ is undefined", "jQuery is undefined" etc.
With the above lines, I am sure that jquery, jquery-ui and formBuilder are all loaded into my bundle.js (I verified by looking into bundle.js code).

4)
In app.js, inside render method, add these 2 elements:

```
<input type="button" value="Load Editor" onClick={this.loadEditor} />
<div id="editor">Editor goes here...</div>
```

5)
In app.js, inside App component, add these 2 methods:

```
// Tries to load editor after component load
componentDidMount() {
  let ed = $("#editor");
  ed.formBuilder();
}

// Tries to load editor on button click {
loadEditor() {
  let ed = $("#editor");
  ed.formBuilder();
}
```

5)
Run app with:
npm start

6)
Open F12 console, you can see this error:

```
index.js:2177 TypeError: N.sortable is not a function
at new A (form-builder.min.js:6)
at HTMLDivElement. (form-builder.min.js:6)
at Function.each (jquery.js:362)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
at form-builder.min.js:6
at
```

7)
Click Load Editor button.
In F12 console, you can see it also gives the same error as in step 6.

8)
Try editing package.json to load the exact same jquery and jquery-ui versions as referenced in Basic Example in http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/:

```
 "jquery": "2.1.4",
 "jquery-ui": "1.11.4",
 "formBuilder": "^2.9.8"
```

The same error still occurs.

Any pointers? We would very much like to use this plugin as we haven't found a WYSIWYG type of form builder for React.

Only app.js and package.json were edited, all other files are unedited (they remain as they were created by create-react-app in step 1).

Comment: I do not recommend using jQuery in a React Application. It isn't easy to integrate and doesn't work well with the basic react-component architecture. I would recommend to use something that is made for react like this library: https://github.com/blackjk3/react-form-builder

Comment: I recommend that you first read this https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html and use `<div ref={el => this.el = el}` approach. Mixing React with jQuery + jQuery-ui + jQuery plugins should be your last option IMHO.

Comment: @Larce The suggested lib is dependent on jQuery ...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has the same problem, I got this to work as follows in a basic React app (created with create-react-app):

package.json:

```
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"jquery-ui-sortable": "*",
"formBuilder": "^2.9.8"
```

app.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require('jquery-ui-sortable');
require('formBuilder');
```

And the same in a React with TypeScript app created with the Visual Studio 2017 React template:

app.js:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
(window as any).jQuery = $;
(window as any).$ = $;
require('jquery-ui-sortable');
require('formBuilder');
```